# Adding ng-mouseover on a image from json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the follwing code :

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<div class="col-md-2-4" ng-class="{'div-hide': index  > $index + 1}" ng-repeat="question in questions">
  <div>{{question.qid}} {{question.question}} </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-s-6 thumb" ng-repeat="image in question.images">
                    <div ng-mouseover="style={'background-color':'gray','cursor':'pointer'}">                   
                        <img class="img-responsive " id="{{image.imageid}} " src="{{image.imgpath}} " alt=" " >
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="keys">
            <button type="button " class="btn btn-next " ng-click="index=index < questions.length ? index + 1 : questions.length ">Next</button>
            <button type="button " class="btn btn-pre " ng-click="index=index> 1 ? index - 1 : 1">Previous</button>
      {{index}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In the img tag i have added a mouse over so that when the mouse goes over the image it will give gray background etc. however its not working. Does anyone know why?

**UPDATEE**

so ive edited it and tried adding css to the div but that does not seem to work either.. heres the updated plunker ..http://plnkr.co/edit/DqNRnc8xYZn73vdkWjaG?p=preview   Please someone helpp!

Comment: ummmm.... because you can't give a 'img' a color, background, or font styling???

Comment: sorry ive edited it. should be on the div ..

Comment: all you are doing is setting the scope's style property to that object. You aren't doing anything to the element. Why don't you define in your css  a hover instead?

Comment: ive tried to add css hover on the image but it just doesnt respond. the image doesnt do anything when i apply the css hover on it. so i thought maybe the ng-mouseover could change the div the image is in when the mouse hovers over it. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#imgbutton:hover, #imgbutton:active {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

This uses CSS to define a hover style.

Comment: Ive added your code to this http://plnkr.co/edit/DqNRnc8xYZn73vdkWjaG?p=preview ... but it doesnt work .. ?

Comment: ive updated it and tried it with css hover. But nothing. Why? is there something wrong with the image?

Comment: I updated my answer to use only CSS which is much simpler.  I tested it in your jsfiddle and it worked even though the images are missing.  Try it in your code and you'll see that it works.